# Java - if object is instance of classA or classB, do

Tags: java

I understand there are also lots of similar questions like this but I think my case is slightly different as I can't find a solution that works well. I will try to explain..

I am using the libgdx game framework, which has classes `TextField` and `TextArea`. `TextArea` is an extension of `TextField`, which has a few additional methods and overrides some of the `TextField` methods, as one might guess, it adds the ability to have multiple lines of text.

I would like both of these classes to contain additional but same methods, so I have extended both of them with classes `TextFieldExt` and `TextAreaExt`. Lets say in both of these I have added the methods `doMethod1()` and `doMethod2()`.

So, I am iterating through the `Actors` (which is the super class of `TextField` and many other objects), when it comes across either `TextFieldExt` or `TextAreaExt` I want it to perform some actions and run `doMethod1()` and `doMethod2()`.

Now what I would like is something like this;

```
if(actor instanceof TextFieldExt || actor instanceof TextAreaExt){
    (...) actor.doMethod1();
}
```

I know this is not possible, and any kind of casting or statement will not allow it since in Java's eyes there is no guarantee these methods exist.

So I tried to build an interface that has the methods I need in both classes, which feels like its going in the right way but I still can't get it working. So for example I have;

```
public interface ExtendedTextElement {
   public void doMethod1();
   public void doMethod2();
}
```

And then in my extended classes I have;

```
public class TextFieldExt extends TextField implements ExtendedTextElement
public class TextAreaExt extends TextArea implements ExtendedTextElement
```

And in my conditional statement I try;

```
if(actor instanceof ExtendedTextElement){ ...
```

Which doesn't work, obviously, because there is no guarantee that the instance is an extension of `TextField` or `TextArea`, so I don't have access to the base methods.

So I am stuck. I can get it to work a bit more manually by having separate conditional statements and duplicate code, but it's quite a lot of code and I would rather there be a proper solution to it.

Comment: Which "base methods" of `TextField` and `TextArea` do you need? And for what purpose? You could potentially just add those method signatures to your `ExtendedTextElement` interface. It would help if you could provide a [small self-contained example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're trying to do, as there are likely several reasonable solutions but they'll depend on your specific requirements.

Comment: If actor is an instance of TextFieldExt then cast it to TextFieldExt and invoke the method. If its instance of TextAreaExt then cast it to TextAreaExt and invoke the method.

Comment: Absolutely unbelievable @dimo414, such a simple solution and it works. Can't believe I didn't even think of that. Thank you!

Comment: @hamham no problem, it's definitely not something you'd assume would work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work for all use-cases, but if all you need to do is call a method that *happens* to be defined by both `TextField` and `TextArea`, you can add that method to your interface, e.g.:

```
public interface ExtendedTextElement {
   public void doMethod1();
   public void doMethod2();
   public void setText(String t);
}
```

You don't say which method(s) of these classes you need, but since they both extend [`TextComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/TextComponent.html) you could also try casting your object to a `TextComponent`. This would work for any method (like `setText()`) that's defined in the shared parent class.

This doesn't work for the `TextField`/`TextArea` case, but if you're dealing with classes that share an interface (instead of a parent class) you can define your interface to extend that one, thereby enforcing that every instance of your interface is also an instance of the shared interface, no `instanceof` checks required.

```
public interface ImaginaryTextComponentInterface {
   public void setText(String t);
}

public interface ExtendedTextElement extends ImaginaryTextComponentInterface {
   public void doMethod1();
   public void doMethod2();
}
```

Comment: It still feels a little manual and hacky, but its by far the best solution I have implemented yet. I guess this kind of work around only really applies if you are manipulating a library or external classes you don't really want to modify too much, otherwise the required methods would go straight into the super (`TextField`) and there would be no need for any of this.

Comment: It definitely is hacky, but it will work. If you can share your actual use case I might be able to offer a better solution to your underlying problem.

Comment: There is quite a lot of functionality I have added, one of them for example is selection handles. These are actually external `Actors` in my `Stage` added at the very end, because they extend outside the boundary of the `TextField`/`TextArea` and need to stay on top of any other elements. In order to do this, some of the additional features I added to the extended class are helpers to get and set the selection area. Ideally these would go into the `TextField` class, but I want to keep my base modifications to an absolute minimum so it's easy to apply my mods to libgdx updates in the future.